# KIE Workbench Integration Responds with 401

Tags: java, curl, web, drools, kie-workbench

I'm trying to integrate my KIE Workbench 6.1.FINAL deployment with a simple application using Drools 6.1.FINAL. I use the following code:

```
String url = "http://localhost:8088/workbench/maven2/com/sep/test/myProject/1.0/myProject-1.0.jar";

KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
UrlResource urlResource = (UrlResource) ks.getResources().newUrlResource(url);
urlResource.setBasicAuthentication("enabled");
urlResource.setUsername("admin");
urlResource.setPassword("admin");

try {
    InputStream is = urlResource.getInputStream();
    KieModule kModule = ks.getRepository().addKieModule(ks.getResources().newInputStreamResource(is));
    kieContainer = ks.newKieContainer(kModule.getReleaseId());
    kieContainer.newStatelessKieSession();

    scanner = ks.newKieScanner(kieContainer);
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception thrown while constructing InputStream");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Every time I run this code, I see the following output:

```
Exception thrown while building InputStream
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8088/workbench/maven2/com/sep/test/myProject/1.0/myProject-1.0.jar
```

I verified that the error is coming from the line getting the `InputStream`. I am able to log in to my workbench at `http://localhost:8088/workbench` with the username and password "admin" and I am able to download the .jar file by following `http://localhost:8088/workbench/maven2/com/sep/test/myProject/1.0/myProject-1.0.jar` in my web browser. I can also retrieve the .jar using the following `curl` command:

```
curl --user admin:admin http://localhost:8088/workbench/maven2/com/sep/test/myProject/1.0/myProject-1.0.jar
```

However, I haven't been able to fetch the .jar using `wget`.

How can I get past the authentication? This is only a prototype; is there a way to turn off authentication for downloading this .jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in UrlResource which has been fixed. See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-693

Here is an alternative solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28230876/418730

Answer (score 0):

it's ok with 6.2.0.Final
and DO NOT use

```
KieModule module = ks.getRepository().addKieModule(urlResource);
```

it also return 401